# nested for function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to start second for from next current first for counter I run this code and this error prevent to run code.
ERROR : type mismatch
This code should show shortest distance cells  as when find next cell(short distance) this cell should remove from search
also I want to return the address(ROW NUMBER) of next cell(shortest distance)

```
`Sub distance()
    Dim j, i As Integer, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("activesheet")
    For i = 2 To 87
    For j = i+1 To 87
    If j <> i Then 
    Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 11).Value =  Sqr(((Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(i, 
    8).Value) - (Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 8).Value)) ^ 2 + 
    ((Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(i, 9).Value) - (Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 
    9).Value)) ^ 2)
    Next j
    ws.Range("l" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(ws.Range("k2:k87"), 1)
    Next i
    End Sub`
```

Comment: 1) Please indent the code properly. 2) Please [debug](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code) the code and explain what you found. (Which line causes the error? What values do the relevant variables have at that point? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I have reformatted your code so I could read it, it would not compile because you were missing an End If (as indicated by a comment in the formatted code below). The code runs fine on a test workbook I have just created. However of course I don't know what source data you have.

```
Sub distance()

Dim j, i As Integer, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("activesheet")

    For i = 2 To 87
        For j = i + 1 To 87
            If j <> i Then
                Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 11).Value = Sqr(((Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(i, 8).Value) - (Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 8).Value)) ^ 2 + ((Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(i, 9).Value) - (Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 9).Value)) ^ 2)
            End If 'this was missing
        Next j
    ws.Range("l" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(ws.Range("k2:k87"), 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Given that this runs okay, I recommend checking the data being used from the worksheet on this line

```
Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 11).Value = Sqr(((Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(i, 8).Value) - (Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 8).Value)) ^ 2 + ((Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(i, 9).Value) - (Worksheets("activesheet").Cells(j, 9).Value)) ^ 2)
```

and this line

```
ws.Range("l" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(ws.Range("k2:k87"), 1)
```

and make sure you are getting data of the correct type. Do you have any words or letters or non numeric data of any kind being used?

To demonstrate the problem, below I am trying to divide the variable A (a string) by the variable B (an integer) and get a type mismatch error as a result.

```
Sub test()

Dim a As String
a = "test"

Dim b As Integer
b = 1

Debug.Print a / b

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you . code have been corrected